# Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am getting the following error when I try to purchase an item again. Please dont close this as duplicate. I know there are many such questions in stack overflow, but none seem to help. Please refer my code.

```
 public class BtnListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    // On-click event handler for all the buttons
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {

            case R.id.TwoSeconds:
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(TimeBoosterActivity.this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                        mPurchaseFinishedListener, "2");
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            //buyButton.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to consume item",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    String getSeconds=purchase.getDeveloperPayload();
                    SharedPreferences saveTwoSeconds=getSharedPreferences(getSeconds, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // handle error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to consume item",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to clear why you got this error (Error response: 7:Item Already Owned)

There are some common case:

① You just buy itemA and not consume it yet;

② Another person (use the same google account with you) just buy this itemA

In case 1: Just consume itemA and you will be able to buy it again.

In case 2: You need to reboot or delete google play service and play store cache. Then use the same google play account consume that itemA.

in case 2, receipt information of itemA is not stored in your device. You  reboot or delete google play service and play store cache to make in-app-billing request to google store to get receipt information of purchase. So you cant consume and buy it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Consume purchase is not being called due to your code in onActivityResult.

Try with below code

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                            Intent data){
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == <Code you sent during launching purchase flow> || requestCode == <Code you sent during launching consume flow> )
     mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data))
   }
}
```